# Magento 2 - How to auto checked a multiselect ui-component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, multiselect, source-model

I have a ui-component

```
        <field name="interest" formElement="multiselect">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">
                    \Model\InterestOptions
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <imports>
                    <link name="customerId">${ $.provider }:data.customer.entity_id</link>
                </imports>
                <label translate="true">Interest</label>
            </settings>

        </field>
```

And the data source come from InterestOptions.php

```
class InterestOptions implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        return [
            'option1' => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 'option1'
            ],
            'option2' => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 'option2'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I auto checked some value by my own logic in my source php?